# margin note left of an equation?

Tags: math-mode, margins, koma-script, marginpar, marginnote

How is it possible to place a margin note left of an equation? I'm using `scrartcl` from `KOMAScript`.

I set `\reversemarginpar`, then I tried with `\marginnote` from the package `marginnote` and also with Latex's own `\marginpar` and with `\marginline` from `KOMAScript`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
\marginnote{test} \begin{align*}
  a &= b \\
  c &= d
\end{align*} \marginnote{test2}
\end{document}
```

The first marginnote (test) is left of the line before the align and the test2 note is next to line after the align. A margin note in the align gives errors. I know I can adjust the vertical offset with marginnote, but that means I have to do it manually (what is not a very good solution IMHO).

How can I place a margin note next to an equation?

Comment: I get no errors when I place `\marginnote` inside the `align` environment

Comment: Ah, you are right. The erros only come with `\marginpar{}`. Seems I didn't tried with `\marginnote` inside align... I voted for a close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can use `\tag` to use an equation label, but offset it into the margin:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newcommand\mathnote[1]{\tag*{\llap{\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{%
\raggedright#1}%
\setbox0\hbox{)}%
\kern\dimexpr\marginparsep+\displaywidth-\wd0\relax}}}}
\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}
\noindent X\dotfill X

\marginnote{test} \begin{align*}
  a &= b\mathnote{test3 . . . . . . . . } \\
  c &= d 
\end{align*} \marginnote{test2 . . . . . . . . . }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea for hwo to handle twocolumn and put this on the inside (middle) margin?