# tufte-latex: math tag into margin

Tags: math-mode, margins, marginpar, tufte, marginnote

How can I push a `\tag` of a math environment into the margin when using tufte-latex? I tried to modify the answer in [margin note left of an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96451/margin-note-left-of-an-equation) but I didn't understand the command.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,justified,marginals=raggedright,nobib]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\geometry{showframe=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a &= b \tag*{since ...}\\
  c &= d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not really clear what exactly you want, is it in general or only this once? And why is this marked `marginnote` (it is a package) when that package is not used i the mwe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we can get rid of the `\marginnote` command provided by the class and use the `marginnote` package, then this seems to work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,justified,marginals=raggedright,nobib]{tufte-book}

\let\marginnote\relax
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\geometry{showframe=true}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   a &= b \tag*{\marginnote{hest}}
  \\
  c &= d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

Try (untested, in a hurry)

```
\let\Tuftemarginnote\marginnote
\let\marginnote\relax
\usepackage{marginnote}
\let\MarginNote\marginnote
\let\marginnote\Tuftemarginnote
```

---

Full combined MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,justified,marginals=raggedright,nobib]{tufte-book}

\let\Tuftemarginnote\marginnote
\let\marginnote\relax
\usepackage{marginnote}
\let\MarginNote\marginnote
\let\marginnote\Tuftemarginnote

\usepackage{mathtools}
\geometry{showframe=true}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
   a &= b \tag*{\MarginNote{test}}
  \\
  c &= d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there are other packages using the original marginnote. Is there a solution without interfering with tufte-book?

Comment: @ManuelSchmidt see my edit

Comment: I accepted your answer, but it would be great if you could merge it into one MWE and explain the `\SL` command.

Comment: Will do, I forgot to remove SL, I used it to see if the baseline lined up